# How to do something like "Touch anywhere to continue"?

Tags: android

How would you do something like "Touch Anywhere to Continue."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an onclick listener for the layout of the entire screen

Comment: how do i set an onclicklistener for a layout?

Comment: @SeungUn: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126268/howto-fire-a-event-when-someone-click-anywhere-on-the-screen-in-a-android-app

Answer (score 0):

### It's as simple as this.

1. Give an id to "main" layout
2. set the listener to the main layout

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout">  //<--- Provide ID

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"     
         />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

In this case, the main element is `RelativeLayout`. So add the listener to `RelativeLayout` to implement **Touch anywhere to continue**.

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

         private RelativeLayout layout;

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             layout   = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
             layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

         }

    }
```