# how to fire an event when someone clicks anywhere on the screen in an android app?

Tags: android, events

how can I catch the event when click occurs somewhere on the app screen?
It doesn't matter if there is a button or something else. I just need to apply an `onClick()` event listener on the whole application screen.

How to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`setonclicklistner` for main layout of your layout file....

Like....main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainlayout">
 <!- Your other view->
</Relativelayout>
```

and set click listener for mainlayout...

```
 RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
 rlayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

 });
```

Comment: What is the full class name of OnClickListener? android.view.View.OnClickListener ?

Comment: android.view.View.OnTouchListener useful for generic x,y touch listening

Comment: it's not working for me when there are lots of child inside layout. Any better solution ?

Comment: App crashes when calling onSetClickListener() in Android O.

Answer (score 13):

You should just override `Activity`'s `dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent)` method

---

Look at this example in Kotlin. This approach **will not affect any onClickListenters** in your app

```
/**
 * On each touch event:
 * Check is [snackbar] present and displayed
 * and dismiss it if user touched anywhere outside it's bounds
 */
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    // dismiss shown snackbar if user tapped anywhere outside snackbar
    snackbar?.takeIf { it.isShown }?.run {
        val touchPoint = Point(Math.round(ev.rawX), Math.round(ev.rawY))
        if (!isPointInsideViewBounds(view, touchPoint)) {
            dismiss()
            snackbar = null // set snackbar to null to prevent this block being executed twice
        }
    }

    // call super
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

Or check out the full [gist](https://gist.github.com/and291/ce5704c4163f8dcd9d06b1ab6a9850cf)

Comment: THATS SUPER AWESOME APPROACH!!!

Comment: Brilliant yet obvious. Can be used to deal with events such as Listeners being fired spuriously. IE: before a real person has begun interaction.

Comment: Could you please write the Java version of this code?

Answer (score 11):

I believe the easiest way is to override [onUserInteraction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction()) in your `Activity`

Just be aware that it won't fire when users focus on/off `EditText`s and `Spinners` (probably other Widgets too). But it will fire every time the user touches the screen or presses a Button.

But this makes it unnecessary to build listeners into your layouts or write additional methods to handle those listeners, so I believe it's the most trouble-free way to get what you want.

Comment: What if we are inside a fragment?

Comment: Works exactly the same inside a fragment. What problem are you encountering?

Comment: onUserInteraction isn't overridable in a fragment

Answer (score 10):

If you want to know, that the user clicked anywhere on the screen
then the trick is to override OnUserUnteraction():

*"Called whenever a key, touch, or trackball event is dispatched to the activity.Implement this method if you wish to know that the user has interacted with the device in some way while your activity is running. This callback and {@link #onUserLeaveHint} are intended to help activities manage status bar notifications intelligently; specifically, for helping activities determine the proper time to cancel a notification...."*

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
...
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Touch anywhere happened");
    super.onUserInteraction();
}
```

I am using it to set up app screen block after some inactivity.

Comment: I am trying to develop an android app to collect touch data from anywhere on the phone while the app is running as a background service. I used WindowManger to create a touch view with an overlay that covers the whole screen to collect all touch data. It works but blocks the interaction with the underneath apps and then cannot use the phone. Can you help me to solve this issue? this is my question posted in StackOverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65299277/get-touch-data-under-service-class-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

Give your main layout an id, then

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
root.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick()
    {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly set a callback from the `onClick` xml attribute of the root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:onClick"myMethod">
 <!- Your other view->
</Relativelayout>
```

And in your activity:

```
public void myMethod(View pView) {
  //XXX do something
}
```

Less bloated code this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a listener to the Layout instance, getting the layout with

```
RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
l.setOnClickListener(click);
```