# how to give an event to the entire screen with so many button and other layout? android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have a project that is calculator, there is many button and layout above the main layout, i have a history frame that hidden at the right screen, i want that if i swipe the edge of the whole screen and ignore the button and other objects there, the history frame shown

i already read the question here

[how to fire an event when someone clicks anywhere on the screen in an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126268/howto-fire-a-event-when-someone-click-anywhere-on-the-screen-in-a-android-app)

but it didnt work for me

thanks

Comment: You  can add swipeListener on Main layout ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using `dispatchTouchEvent`.