# Get touch data under service class in android studio

Tags: android, service, touch

I developed an App to collect the touch events under the foreground service class. The app has main activity to input user's information (e.g., name and age). Then when "RUN" button on the menu items is selected by the user, a foreground service starts to collect touch events, and a notification is launched to inform the user that the service is running.

## This is the main activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.run_catch:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                intent = new Intent(this, SensorService.class);
                this.startForegroundService(intent);
                setStartPreferences(true);
                isStart = true;
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(this, SensorService.class);
                this.startService(intent);
                setStartPreferences(true);
                isStart = true;
            }


            break;
        case R.id.stop_catch:
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SensorService.class);
            stopService(intent);

            setStartPreferences(false);
            isStart = false;
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Inside the Oncreate function of the service class, I initialized the touch function using the new "Linear layout" with the "WindowManger".

## This is the service class code:

```
public class SensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener, LocationListener, View.OnTouchListener{
//Touch
private WindowManager windowManager;
private LinearLayout touchLayout;
 @Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    try {
        initTouch();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notification();
}

public void initTouch() {  //Touch
    touchLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    windowManager = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    touchLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    windowManager.addView(touchLayout, params);
     }


 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Touch Event occur"+ "\n"+ motionEvent.getX() + "\n"+ motionEvent.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  return true;
}
```

I also tried to call the initTouch() function from inside "onStartCommand()" but still not working.
Can anyone help me to get touch events (e.g., X, Y coordinates of the touches) of the user when interacting with our app's linear layout (or other apps in the smartphone) while the app running under the service class?

Comment: The problem was in the type of flag that I used. In detail, since I use android API28 version 9, the "WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE" is deprecated and replaced by"WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY". Then I can correctly get the touch events such as X and Y values of the touches but for ONLY the underly app; touches OUTSIDE return always zeros values. Can anyone help?